# Cookie или localStorage?

Tags: cookie, localstorage

Что лучше использовать для сохранения статуса о админе, Cookie или LocalStorage? Мне нужно надежное хранилище и на регулируемый промежуток времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прочтите тут думаю тут более упрощенный ответ на ваш вопрос.

http://sneakbug8.com/cookies-js-storages

Comment: Было бы неплохо перенести основное из текста по ссылке в сам ответ.